# Convert the multiple rows Select statement result into a single row string result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the following sql query. I'd like the results to be concatenated with a `,` and I need this as one single query.

```
Select LOCATION_CODE from LOCATION WHERE ZIPCODE = '555555';
```

**Location table**

```
  location_id | location_code   |  zipcode
--------------------------------------------
      1       |    ASDFSFD      |  555555    
      2       |    OUIXVCX      |  555555
      3       |    2KLJSDF      |  555555
      14      |    887CSD       |  555555
```

Need the results like below...   `ASDFSFD,OUIXVCX,2KLJSDF,887CSD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with location_code as (
select 'ASDFSFD' loc_code, 555555 zipcode from dual
union all select 'OUIXVCX', 555555 from dual
union all select '2KLJSDF', 555555 from dual
union all select '887CSD', 555555 from dual
)
select rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, loc_code || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') 
from location_code where zipcode = 555555;
```

Comment: You can do the following to use a custom delimiter: `rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, loc_code || '|')).extract ('//text()'), '|')` where `|` is a custom delimiter. It even appears to work with multi-character delimiters (e.g., `||`). This is a great solution by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 10g, you can also use the undocumented aggregate function `WM_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT WM_CONCAT(location_code) FROM location WHERE zipcode = 555555;
```

One possible caveat is that `WM_CONCAT()` returns a CLOB in some versions of Oracle 10g (e.g., 10.2.0.5), but a VARCHAR2 in others (e.g., 10.2.0.1).

You can also develop your own string concatenation aggregate function; please see the following links for specifics (as well as other methods of how to accomplish string concatenation):

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#wm_concat

Comment: I like this approach very well. I get clob, so, I convert it to char by using to_char()

Comment: Also, is there a way we can use a custom delimiter instead of a ,? i'm still reading up from the link, did not find any so far.

Comment: This isn't possible with `WM_CONCAT()` but it is possible if you write your own custom aggregate function (which instructions are included in the link). For example, if you look at the member function `ODCIAggregateIterate` you can see where the string is concatenated with a comma delimiter, and replace that delimiter with a custom one. Keep in mind that there are actually three member functions to update.

Comment: Also in Oracle 11 you have the `LISTAGG()` analytic function.

Comment: Also see my comment on the accepted solution from @Multisync above.